# how to pass model class with three class properties to pass value through the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model class I have two `class` and i have complied first two `class` in the third `class` in the first class property value is passed in the controller but other two class values are not passed in the controller field.

```
div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabs-1-tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="tabs-1-tab-1">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model =>Model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-label semibold control-label" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Company Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.CompanyName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Short Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.ShortName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Division" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Division)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your Email" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Email)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" onclick=" GetInfo();" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-2">
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtFaceBookID", placeholder = "Enter the Facebook Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTwitterID", placeholder = "Enter the Twitter Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtlinkedinID", placeholder = "Enter the Linkedin Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="saveSocial" value="Next" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-3">
                        Tab 3
                        <br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Finish" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section><!--.tabs-section-->
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax Call method:

```
<script>
        function GetInfo() {
            var company = { companyName: document.getElementById('CompanyName').value, shortName: document.getElementById('ShortName').value, division: document.getElementById('Division').value, Email: document.getElementById('Email').value }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Company/AddCompany",
                data: '{cmp:' + JSON.stringify(company) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#saveSocial").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                GetInfo1();
            });
        });

        function GetInfo1() {
            //var Social = { faceBook: document.getElementById('FaceBookID').value, twitter: document.getElementById('TwitterID').value, linkedin: document.getElementById('linkedinID').value }
            var Social = { "facebook": $("#txtFaceBookID").val() };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Company/AddSocial",
                data: '{Social:' + JSON.stringify(Social) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

the image attached below [image: Class image] the textbox value is not passed.

in  `ActionResult AddSocial` controller method when i click the button textbox 
 value is not passed..

```
ActionResult AddCompany in this controller method the value is passed.
```

bellow i have attached the image:

[image: Addsocial]

Class method:

```
[Table("CompanyRegistration")]
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the Company Name")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Short Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the Short Name")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("CompanySocialNetwork")]
    public class CompanySocial
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanySocialID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string FaceBookID { get; set; }
        public string TwitterID { get; set; }
        public string linkedinID { get; set; }
    }


    public class MainModel
    {
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public CompanySocial CompanySocial { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Its `var Social = { FaceBookID: $("#txtFaceBookID").val() };` and `data: JSON.stringify{ CompanySocial : Social },` - your names need to match your property names

Comment: Do you have `@model MainModel` line on top of AddSocial view?

Comment: @added but it's not working?@Ikram Turgunbaev

Comment: thanks @ Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply not passing the correct model to your controller.

```
function GetInfo1() {
    //var Social = { faceBook: document.getElementById('FaceBookID').value, twitter: document.getElementById('TwitterID').value, linkedin: document.getElementById('linkedinID').value }
    var Social = { "facebook": $("#txtFaceBookID").val() };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Company/AddSocial",
        data: '{Social:' + JSON.stringify(Social) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

will pass a parameter like

```
{
    faceBook: "",
    twitter: "",
    linkedin: ""
}
```

but you need

```
{
    company: {},
    CompanySocial: {
        FaceBookID: "",
        TwitterID: "",
        linkedinID: ""
    }
}
```

so you have to change `GetInfo1` to something like

```
function GetInfo1() {
    var Social = { FaceBookID: document.getElementById('FaceBookID').value, TwitterID: document.getElementById('TwitterID').value, linkedinID: document.getElementById('linkedinID').value }

    var mainModel = {};
    mainModel.CompanySocial = Social;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Company/AddSocial",
        data: JSON.stringify(mainModel),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```